# How to surround item of list label text with customized symbols?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I would like to surround the item text of my customized list with some symbols (say, parentheses or brackets).

Here is a sample text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{ProofEnumDesc}{description}{2}
\setlist[ProofEnumDesc]{style=sameline}
\begin{document}
\begin{ProofEnumDesc}
\item[Case1] balabala
\item[Case2] xxxxx
\end{ProofEnumDesc}
\end{document}
```

Instead of being like

[image]

I want the output document to be

[image]

***without*** changing the item text such as `\item[Case1]` to be `\item[(Case1)]`.

Note that I hope to make this customized list flexible enough since more styles for the label text may be also be added in the future; therefore I tend not to modify the item text manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a new value to `align` key with the command `\SetLabelAlign`.  Then you use it in your `\setlist`.  Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\SetLabelAlign{parenboth}{(#1)\hfil}
\newlist{ProofEnumDesc}{description}{2}
\setlist[ProofEnumDesc]{style=sameline,align=parenboth}

\begin{document}

\begin{ProofEnumDesc}
\item[Case1] Text
\item[Case2] Text
\end{ProofEnumDesc}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: How can I get the document about this? I don't know how to search via `texdoc`.

Comment: @HongxuChen - Try `texdoc texdoc` to get the documentation to `texdoc` itself.  Usually, you do `texdoc <package name>`, in this case `texdoc enumitem`.